# Erro ao adcionar um texto com o django 3, como consertar isso?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

```
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

Pra mim estava tudo bem eu tinha meu modelo que fazia com que o usuário escrevesse um topico e ele podia colocar um assunto relacionado a ele como na imagem do minha pagina de admin a seguir:

[image: Minha pagina de admin]
Porem ao salvar meu texto ocorria um Erro que eu não entendo o porquê...

[image: Traceback]

## Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não manda print do erro e sim a mensagem.

Comment: Você não criou a migration... `python manage.py makemigrations` depois `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: criei sim...ele ainda fez um arquivo na pasta migrations:

Answer (score 0):

Opa eu já encontrei a solução!

em:

```
text = models.TextField()
```

o banco de dados não cria uma table nomeada text
mas se colocarmos:

```
text = models.TextField(auto_created=True)
```

e migrar novamente dá  certo...